# What is the replacement for MailDefinition in .Net 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0

First time posting and very new with .Net 6 and ASP.NET Core.

I am converting an old project which uses `MailDefinition` to send mails out which have a HTML template, [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.maildefinition?view=netframework-4.8.1.) This link indicates its not supported for .Net 6.

The current code is very similar to this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d9c87a/send-templated-emails-using-maildefinition-object-in-Asp-Net/)

My alternative is to use a file reader for the file and then replace the content values however this seems to be a little old school and wondered if there was another replacement class for `MailDefinition` considering I'm using .Net 6?

Thanks

I read this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.maildefinition?view=netframework-4.8.1)  which doesn't give indication of the class being supported in .Net 6.

I have viewed this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d9c87a/send-templated-emails-using-maildefinition-object-in-Asp-Net/) which doesn't use .Net 6

I am expecting the equivalent function or replaceable class for .Net 6 without having to rewrite a large amount of code.